# secure xml parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Hi i am able to parse a normal xml like xml = lxml.etree.parse(''http://abc.com/A.xml')
but now i have this path authenticated with a user name and password is it possible to input the username and password and parse the url, like in connecting a database where you can give the user name password in the connection string

Comment: -1. You refuse to accept answers and you ignore this fact when told to do so. Learn to reciprocate.

Comment: sorry abt that i am kind a new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guys i found a way to parse password protected XML this is what i did.

```
import urllib2
import base64
theurl = 'http://abc.com/A.xml'

username='AAA'
password='BBB'

req = urllib2.Request(theurl)


base64string = base64.encodestring(
            '%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    print "It looks like the username or password is wrong."
xml = handle.read()
inputXml  = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Before parsing the XML document with `lxml`, you need to get it by making an HTTP request that handles the HTTP Basic/Digest Authentication properly. For example, with `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` like in this solution: [Python urllib2 HTTPBasicAuthHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078638/python-urllib2-httpbasicauthhandler)