# urllib2.urlopen('xxx') return 401 but when open with browser return 200

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

urllib2.urlopen('xxx') return 401 but when open with browser return 200.
I have added header to simulate but still 401, the website is built on IIS server.

Comment: Is it possible to show us the url?

Comment: it's an internal link...any idea which part may cause this kind of issue?

Comment: 401 means authorization fault. Maybe your browser stored your access_token (For example, you can automatically login StackOverFlow for a long time once you logined via username and password). But to use urllib, you have to provide the authroization information. (This is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078638/python-urllib2-httpbasicauthhandler))

Comment: Hi thx for reply. yea, 401 means needs auth, but when i open with the browser it also requests me to input passwd and username, which return 200, it's supposed i could get the page at least.