# Why is my basic auth handler not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, basic-authentication

I want to scrape a page that's behind a basic http auth. I can use `wget http://user:pass@example.com/path/to/the_thing` just fine. But if I try to access it via `urllib2` it isn't authorizing.

I read through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) as well as [Python urllib2 HTTPBasicAuthHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078638/python-urllib2-httpbasicauthhandler) and this seems like it ought to work, but I'm getting `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`. So it isn't working.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

very_beginning = "http://www.example.com/mm/path/to/the_thing"
my_user = "user"
my_passwd = "hella_secret"


auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(
                realm="clinty",
                uri="http://example.com/mm/",
                user=my_user,
                passwd=my_passwd
                )
auth_opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(auth_opener)

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(very_beginning))
    # return soup
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It's simpler to use the `requests` library for this. An example from [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/): `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details are required to know what's going wrong but here's another syntax you might want to try:

```
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, my_user, my_passwd)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
```

from there you can confirm that it's working with:

```
auth_opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(auth_opener)

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(very_beginning))
    print("success")
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: I can't pass the `handler` to Beautiful Soup though.

Comment: You'd use the handler just like your `auth_handler`. E.g. `auth_opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)`